# Spring Data web pagination "page" parameter not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, pagination, spring-data

I'm trying to get Spring Data's web pagination working. It's described here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#web-pagination

Here's my Java (Spring Web MVC @Controller handler method):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(
    @PageableDefaults(value = 50, pageNumber = 0) Pageable pageable,
    Model model) {

    log.debug("Params: pageNumber={}, pageSize={}",
        pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize());

    ...
}
```

And here's my Spring configuration:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableArgumentResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

(It appears that the configuration above is the way to do this now; the configuration approach described in the link is deprecated.)

When I actually try to control the pagination using the `page` and `page.size` parameters, the latter works just fine, but the former doesn't. For example, if I hit

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/list?page=14&page.size=42
```

the log output is

```
Params: pageNumber=0, pageSize=42
```

So I know that the argument resolver is kicking in, but not sure why it's not resolving the page number. I've tried a bunch of other param names (e.g. page.number, pageNumber, page.num, etc.) and none of them work.

Is this working for anybody else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the page parameter is actually a bit non-intuitive - `page.page` and not `page`, changing to `page.page` should get things to work.

Comment: Spring 3< uses `page`, `size`, `sort`

Answer (score 2):

Looking into the `PageableArgumentResolver` I found that `prefix` and `separator` are configurable, so you can configure the class not to have it.

```
public class PageableArgumentResolver implements WebArgumentResolver {

    private static final Pageable DEFAULT_PAGE_REQUEST = new PageRequest(0, 10);
    private static final String DEFAULT_PREFIX = "page";
    private static final String DEFAULT_SEPARATOR = ".";
```

in my @Configuration class I did something different to achieve using `page`, `size`,`sort` and `sortDir` as default.

```
@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    PageableArgumentResolver resolver =  new PageableArgumentResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("");
    resolver.setSeparator("");
    argumentResolvers.add(new ServletWebArgumentResolverAdapter(resolver));
}
```

Now this works

> http://:8080/myapp/list?page=14&size=42

Answer (score 0):

You can override parameters if you want by doing:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean   class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver">
            <property name="oneIndexedParameters" value="true"></property>
            <property name="pageParameterName" value="page"></property>
            <property name="sizeParameterName" value="size"></property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: Nik - If we set oneIndexedParameters to true, then what should be the pageIndex should go ?